# In ASP.NET, what is the quickest way to get the base URl for a request?

Tags: asp.net, url, request

Is there a fast way to get the scheme, host, port (only if not 80) and application path in ASP.NET?

As far as I know, I need to assemble the following pieces:

- Request.Url.Scheme
- Request.Url.SchemeDelimiter
- Request.Url.Authority (although that will probably always include the port even when it's 80)
- Request.ApplicationPath

Isn't there a simple property for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```

Note that this may or may not end with a trailing "/" depending on if your app is hosted in the root of the site or in a sub directory.