# CSS background-image won't show with short URL

Tags: css, short-url

I've done my searching and the topics haven't been of help.

I'm trying to have the background image of my header repeat across the X axis of the header div.

When I make CSS with a long URL such as

`background-image:url('http://site.com/images/logo.png');` everything works fine

When I try to shorten the CSS to something such as ~/images/ or even having the CSS and site file already in the root folder and using /images/ I get nothing

```
background-image:url('~/images/logo.png')

background-image:url('/images/logo.png')
```

Comment: `/images/` should work. Can you check in Firebug's "Net" tab what the full request  ends up looking like, and what response you get back?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but single quoting your resource paths inside of `url()` doesn't work in IE5 for Mac. The preferred style is to not quote them at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possibly because you're not shortening your URLs appropriately.

Assuming an absolute path of:

```
url('www.example.com/images/imageName.png');
```

A root-relative URL would be:

```
url('/images/imageName.png');
```

And a relative path (assuming your CSS file is in `www.example.com/css/cssStylesheet.css`) would be:

```
url('../images/imageName.png'); /* parent directory, then the images directory */
```

The `~` prefixed url format is unknown to me, though I suspect it's an ASP, or .NET, form? Though I'm unable to advise on that.

Questions that might be of use to you:

- [How do I turn a relative URL into a full URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126242/how-do-i-turn-a-relative-url-into-a-full-url)
- [Using relative URL in CSS file, what location is it relative to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to)
- [Absolute urls, relative urls, and...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904046/absolute-urls-relative-urls-and)

Answer (score 0):

A URL containing "~" is something that's specific to ASP.NET, it's processed server-side and transformed into a "proper" URL such as `http://mysite/my_virtual_directory/images/logo.png`. Web Browsers don't have any way to do this as they don't know to what "~" refers.

You need to ensure that the URLs you use in your CSS file are "understandable" by the browser, so either have them "fully qualified" (`http://mysite/my_virtual_directory/images/logo.png`) or starting from the "beginning" (`/my_virtual_directory/images/logo.png`).