# Absolute url in meta tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

How to set absolute url in meta tags? Let's say I have the tag below in my MVC4 web app.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="~/content/logo-large.png" />
```

When I run web app I get relative Url resolved in href but I need to get absolute url.

Answer (score 0):

Luke Duddridge already pointed you to [the correct post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126242/how-do-i-turn-a-relative-url-into-a-full-url), here is a link to the most useful answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020514/177710. Use it like this:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="@Url.AbsoluteContent("~/content/logo-large.png")" />
```